# What is difference between OS5 MenuItem Class and OS6 MenuItem Class In Blackberry

Tags: api, blackberry

I am new to BlackBerry, still I developed apps for BlackBerry OS 5.

I know MenuItem class in BlackBerry is used for creating menuitems in Blackberry. My friend told me, one can also crate menuitems using MenuItem class and Command Framework API in Blackberry OS6. Then I googled it. I did not find anything, what's the difference between them?

Comment: look here you can under stand look for the constructor summary of [DOCS JDE5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#MenuItem(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) and [DOCS jde6.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#MenuItem(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MenuItem has been deprecated in OS6.
Here is a link to the doc for its replacement
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/command/package-summary.html

Some fundamental changes have happened to the navigation in BBOS6, it now has Popup menus and Submenus.

**APIs**

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/menu/SubMenu.html

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/menu/CommandItem.html

**Overviews**

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Submenus_6_0_1133451_11.jsp

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Popup_menus_1133453_11.jsp